# Android Twitter open source client

Tags: android

Where can I get the code of a Twitter client for Android? Possibly a recent one using the latest SDK. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Google was supposed to open source the official twitter app... 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html

> we’ll soon be open sourcing this application code under the Android Open Source Project.

but it never happened :(

Answer (score 0):

You can start here: [Source Forge - Twitter for Android](http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=android+twitter)

Comment: -1. Pointing to a search engine which only yielded useless results?

Answer (score 0):

I have coded a "very" simple Twitter client which implements Sign-in with twitter functionality.

maybe it doesn't give you exactly what you want/expect, but it might give you an idea.

http://thetechnib.blogspot.com/2011/01/android-sign-in-with-twitter.html

Answer (score 0):

I only found this, twitli. http://www.twitli.com/download.html

Answer (score 0):

I've found [TwAPIme](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twapime.app), which is open source.  The source code is available [here](http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/downloads/directory/TwAPIme), and targets Android version 1.5 and above.

[AndTweet](http://code.google.com/p/andtweet/) is another open twitter application, but this require Android 1.6 and above.

[Twimight](http://code.google.com/p/twimight/) is another, but details on the webpage are scarce.

Sorry I haven't found any open source twitter applications specifically targeting Android 4.0 and above.

Answer (score -1):

By Using code we can directly get the twitter log in page

```
Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse("http://mobile.twitter.com"));
                startActivity(i);
```

Comment: well, actually I meant an open source full Twitter client

Comment: I don't think this is what he asked :-P